# How to turn list of lists into dictionary in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, hierarchy

I have a list that represents some kind of hieracrhy like this:

```
[[[root]], [[part1, part2, part3]],[[],[ part1 of part2, part2 of part2],[part1 of part3]]]
```

I want it to look like this:

```
root
    part1
    part2
        part1 of part 2
        part2 of part 2
    part3
        part 1 of part 3
```

I can make it look like the above if I can turn that list of lists.. to a dictionary
So how can I turn that list of lists of lists to a dictionary or display it like the above in some other way.
Note: I need to do this in much deeper and larger lists

Comment: Is it not clear how your final outcome would look like in python. Do you mean you need a dictionary like `my_dict = {"root": {"part1": {{...}}, "part2": {"part1 of part2": {...}, "part2 of part2": {...}}, "part3":{"part1 of part3":{...}}} }`? Or can you write the final pythonic outcome you expect?